# How to line up these components correctly, in MigLayout

Tags: clojure, miglayout

I can't seem to get a very simple form, to line up the components in a predictable way.

For example, 3 multi-line text components `txtTest01`, `txtTest02`, and `txtTest03`.

> txtTest01 - 80 columns, 15 rows
>   txtTest02 - 50 columns, 15 rows
>   txtTest03 - 30 columns, 15 rows

I'm trying to line them up, so that `txtTest01` is on top.  Then `txtTest02` starts on the next row after `txtTest01`.  `txtTest03` starts in the column to the right of `txtTest02`, and it's right edge should line up with the first text box `txtTest01`.

So there should be 1 component at the top of the form, and 2 components below it.
Something like this:

> txtTest01txtTest01txtTest01_
>   txtTest02txtTest02 txtTest03

(This is a simplification of the actual form I'm working on, gaps don't need to be considered.  The actual form has listboxes, but of course they aren't lining up.)

I've tried several dozen permutations of this, over the past week, but nothing seems to work to line these up.

Here is the one that makes the most sense to me, but it doesn't produce the expected results:

```
layout flowy
txtTest01 wrap
txtTest02 flowx wrap
txtTest03
```

What happens as a result of this, is that `txtTest01` shows up in the proper position.  `txtTest02` wraps all right, but it wraps to the next COLUMN after `txtTest01`, rather than below it. The first column of `txtTest03` lines up directly BELOW the first column of `txtTest02`.

... And yes, I've read the documentation, and have come to the conclusion that I'm stupid & need some help.

Comment: Please provide some code or SSCCE. Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with from you kinda rough explanation:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug, fill, wrap 2", "[grow 2, fill][grow 1, fill]", "[grow, fill]"));

        mainPanel.add(new JTextArea("Textarea 1"), "spanx 2");
        mainPanel.add(new JTextArea("Textarea 2"), "");
        mainPanel.add(new JTextArea("Textarea 3"), "");


        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: Tom, thanks much for the quick assistance.  It actually clears up some other confusions that I've had, about the documentation.  

Yeah, I didn't include the original code, because it's in Clojure Seesaw, and the syntax difference might have over-complicated the question.

But your solution does work, thanks.  Here are the relevant Clojure snippets, based on your suggestions:




(def txtTest01 ( s/text :multi-line? true :font "MONOSPACED-PLAIN-14"
:text "1
1
1
1
")
)

( .setColumns txtTest01 nNumberOfTextBoxColumns )
( .setRows txtTest01 15 )

( comment defs of txtTest02, txtTest03 )
...

Comment: ...

( def mpTest ( mig-panel :constraints [ "debug, fill, wrap 2", "[grow 2, fill][grow 1, fill]", "[grow, fill]" ] ) )

( def frmTest ( s/frame :content mpTest  :on-close :exit ) )

( add! mpTest [ txtTest01 "spanx 2" ] )

( add! mpTest [ txtTest02 ] )

( add! mpTest [ txtTest03 ] )

Comment: I think you're right. The Clojure syntax with MigLayout would have confused me. Otherwise there sure would have been people who could help you with Clojure and MigLayout. (But if my answer still helped you, you're welcome)

Answer (score 0):

Although the following is still simplified, and has already been modified to include other components, this is the Clojure result of Tom's suggestions.  If anyone is having a hard time with Clojure/Seesaw/MigLayout, I hope this helps:

```
  (ns seesaw02.core
  (:require [seesaw.core :as s])
  (:gen-class)
  ( :use [ seesaw core mig ] )
  )

( s/native! )


( def nNumberOfTextBoxColumns 80 )


( def txtOutput
  ( s/text :multi-line? true :font "MONOSPACED-PLAIN-14"
:text
"This
is
the
text
output
box"
  )
)

( .setColumns txtOutput ( - nNumberOfTextBoxColumns 30 ) )
( .setRows txtOutput 15 )




( def txtInput ( s/text :font "MONOSPACED-PLAIN-14" :background "#888" :foreground :blue ) )
( .setColumns txtInput nNumberOfTextBoxColumns )


( def txtExtraInput 
  ( s/text :multi-line? true :font "MONOSPACED-PLAIN-14"
:text
"This
is
the
Extra
Input
textbox"
  )
)

( .setColumns txtExtraInput ( - nNumberOfTextBoxColumns 30 ) )
( .setRows txtExtraInput 15 )


(def lbHistory ( s/listbox :model ( -> '( "what" "the" "heeeeell" "is" "going" "on?" ) )))


( def mpTest ( mig-panel :constraints [ "fill, wrap 2", "[ grow 2, fill ] [ grow 1, fill ]", "[ grow, fill ]" ] ) )
( def frmTest ( s/frame :content mpTest :on-close :exit ) )
( add! mpTest [ txtOutput "spanx 2" ] )
( add! mpTest [ txtInput "spanx 2" ] )
( add! mpTest [ txtExtraInput ] )
( add! mpTest [ lbHistory ] )


(defn -main
  [& args]
  ( s/invoke-later
    (
      doto frmTest
      s/show!
      s/pack!
    )
   )
 )
```